# Replacing pattern in R using gsub

Tags: r, gsub

I am having an issue in replacing `opp` with `opportunity`

using the below code , it works well; however when there is `opportunity` as a word it gets replaced by `opportunityortunity`

How to solve this issue

```
data <- c("opp", "opportunity")

gsub("opp", "opportunity", data)
```

Comment: Why do you need a `gsub` for this? Simple `ifelse(data == "opp","oppurtunity",data)` would have been good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data <- c("opp", "opportunity", "support product opp ")

gsub("\\bopp\\b", "opportunity", data)
[1] "opportunity"             "opportunity"              "support product opportunity "
```

`\\b` matches the end of a word and should work for both spaces and end of lines `$`. I put it at both ends just in case – although the first one might be skipped on your current example data.